# Why would the top print() statement print to the console after a later line of code

Tags: python, output

[code output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWIXw.png)

one.func() returns the output *"top level one .py"* and *"one.py has been imported"* which appears before the output line "top level two.py".

```py
import one
print("top level two.py")

one.func() 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("two.py being run directly")

else:
    print("two is being imported")'''
```

The one.py module is:

```
def func():
    print("func in one.py")


print("top level one.py")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("one.py is being run directly")
else:
    print("one.py has been imported")
```

Comment: Don't post images of code, post the code

Comment: You *must* provide a [mcve]

Comment: What is this mysterious `one` that you are importing? Why not include it since your question involves it?

Comment: I don't know how to represent that this comes from another module outside of this block of code. in this case its a function from another module returning the output shown.

Comment: @DallonBoultbee again, **you must provide a [mcve]**. Just provide *both modules*

Comment: Almost certainly, the module `one` has some `print` at the global scope producing those outputs.

Comment: @DallonBoultbee no, it isn't, because you haven't provided a [mcve]. I'm not even sure what you mean, you've *already posted code here*, just post the other module

Comment: It seems the mysterious `one` module is wreaking havoc on your terminal output :-) In all seriousness, this almost certainly looks like you have two `print` statements in the module being imported.

Comment: ok well thats helpful at least I thought something like this.

Comment: Thanks for updating your question, voted to re-open

Comment: ty for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you are importing one before printing "top level two.py". if one.py looks like this:

```py
print("top level one.py")

def func():
    #do something 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("one.py being run directly")

else:
    print("one.py has been imported")
```

and with the two.py code above, then one.py is run first, when it is imported.
Because one is running first, then its print statements will happen before the prints in two, and so they will show up first.

Comment: thank you for your feedback. I'm going to take a little bit to wrap my head around this

Comment: When you import a module, all the code at the top level is executed. For lines such as print statements, they will take effect. For things like function or class definitions, executing it means that the function or class object is created so that it can be called at another location.